# Dynamic ID - How to click a dynamic button with selenium in Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

the button is a copy one; that copies the file sharing link in the upper box. Here's my attempt at it:

```
getLink = driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[starts-with(@id, "ic0") and contains(@id, "544")]""").click()
```

Still didn't work. The class is '#c0-5443772' but it is dynamic.

Appreciate the help, folks!

HTML code of the page: https://codeshare.io/2WxgOy
Screenshot of the page:

[png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0WYaT.png)

Comment: can u pls share html code for button or your url

Comment: In order to help you we need to see that page HTML, preferable the link to the page itself

Comment: Screenshot and sourcecode is updated in the post! @Sonali

Comment: which button you want to click ?

Comment: The copy button or anything that copies the link in the box above. @cruisepandey

Comment: there are 4 copy buttons, any specific one ?

Comment: Fourth one. @cruisepandey

Comment: Updated answer below with different combination @Dannie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For clicking on copy button which is available for download link, you may use the below xpath :

```
//h2[text()='Download Link']//following-sibling::button
```

Similarly you may use the below Xpath for Link for forums

```
//h2[text()='Link for forums']//following-sibling::button
```

for the last and 4th button, you may use the below xpath :

```
//h2[text()='Embed code']//following-sibling::button
```

for Paste you can use pyperclip

Make sure to install using pip `pip install pyperclip`

```
paste_string= pc.paste();
  
print(paste_string)
```

**Update 1 :**

```
from time import sleep
import tkinter as tk
import clipboard as clipboard
import pyautogui as pyautogui
import pyperclip as pyperclip
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import pandas as pd

driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\Selenium+Python\\chromedriver.exe")
driver.maximize_window()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 100)
driver.get("https://www.streamsb.com/login.html")

#   Login

user = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#login > div > form > div:nth-child(3) > div > input[type=text]").send_keys("Enter here")
password = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#login > div > form > div:nth-child(4) > div > input[type=password]").send_keys("Enter here")
enter = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#login > div > form > div:nth-child(7) > div > input[type=submit]").click()
#   Navigation and upload
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#mAcct > div.mnu > div > ul > li:nth-child(1) > a").click()
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#mainmenu > ul > li:nth-child(2) > a").click()
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#filepc").send_keys("C:\\Selenium+Python\\file_example_MP4_480_1_5MG.mp4")

uploadButton = driver.find_element_by_class_name("upload-form-button").click()

copy_button = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'button.btndiv')))

print("before clicking copy button.")
copy_button.click()

text = clipboard.paste() # text will have the content of clipboard
print(text)
```

Comment: So, I've done this: getLink = `driver.find_element_by_xpath("//h2[text()='Embed code']//following-sibling::button").click()` if it's clicked the copy button, then logically the link will be stored in the clipboard but it doesn't store the link.

Comment: How did you determine that it did not store the link ?

Comment: Because I pasted and whatever I'd copied was still there.

Comment: You can use pyperclip to paste the value, updated my answer. Check it out.

Comment: Nothing comes up when I run it. Could you run my code. https://codeshare.io/2WxrWE

Comment: @Dannie : Yes I did run it on my local and it works fine, update the answer above. Let me know for any issue

Comment: Thank you so much! I've replaced the user n PW with "Enter here" for security reasons.

Answer (score 0):

there are four Copy Html codes for 4 tabs and each has a different id but the same class. So you can use your XPath something like this.

```
"//h2[contains(.,'"+tabName+"')]//following-sibling::button"
```

Here tab Name is the Variable that would pass as the tab Names value
eg.

`//h2[contains(.,'Download Link')]//following-sibling::button`

Comment: Not working. The clipboard doesn't have the link still.

Comment: The clipboard has the link in the runtime. You need to write code to paste in the required place in the runtime or that button functionality is not working which I hardly doubt is the case. But you should not get error for not identifying the copy button

Comment: I've tried this: `getLink = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//h2[text()='Download Link']//following-sibling::button").click()
print(pyperclip.paste(getLink))` Nothing showed up when I've ran it.